# GETDATE() throwing exception

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a simple application where i am using **MSAccess** as database.
When i am trying to retrieve the data using below query - i am getting exception **undefined function GETDATE()**

```
select *
from tempdata
where dateissue  between DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) - 0 , 0) 
and  DATEADD(MM,         DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, - 1 )
```

can't we use the sql inbuilt methods inside c# code ?? if so how do i solve this problem

Comment: i have added one more columnn in the MS Access database and final query is look like      SELECT count(Usercategory) as category_count ,Usercategory  FROM tempdata where IssueDate between DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, DATE()) - 0 , 0) and  DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, DATE()) + 1, - 1 )  group by category But now i am getting some different error "No value given for one or more required parameters." -- i am not able to figure out any error with this

Comment: Please mark any answer that solves your original question as solved.  Then post a new question that pertains to this new issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you moved past the first problem (there is no `GETDATE()` function in Access SQL), you have discovered another problem.

The [DateAdd Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx) requires a *"String expression that is the interval of time you want to add"* as its first argument, *Interval*.  But you're giving it `MM` instead:

```sql
DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, DATE()) - 0 , 0)
```

I don't understand what interval you're trying to add.  If you want to add minutes, use ...

```sql
DateAdd('n', ...
```

If you want to add months, use ...

```sql
DateAdd('m', ...
```

If you want to add days, use ...

```sql
DateAdd('d', ...
```

Note `DateDiff()` also expects an *Interval* string argument and the allowable values are the same as those for `DateAdd()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Actually i am looking to get the current month data, i.e. data between  1 - 30 of the current month [ here i am not considering time] final query --> SELECT     UserCategory
FROM         User_cat
WHERE     (IssueDate BETWEEN DATEADD('m', DATEDIFF('m', 0, DATE()) - 0, 0) AND DATEADD('m', DATEDIFF('m', 0, DATE()) + 1, - 1))
GROUP BY UserCategory  -- i have data for the current month but still no records are appearing

Comment: That's much different than the question you asked here.  I suggest you submit that as a new question and include data from `User_cat` showing sample `UserCategory` and `IssueDate` values.  Also show the output you want based on those data.  That question would interest me, and I would attempt an answer unless someone else gets there first.  :-)

Comment: Thanks i have added new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669319/msaccess-query-not-returning-any-result

Answer (score 8):

GETDATE() is not a function inside MSAccess.  The equivilant would be:

**Now()** provides date and time

**Date()** provides the date

**Time()** provides the time

Answer (score 3):

In MS ACCESS equivalent of `GETDATE()` is  `DATE()`

Comment: i have added one more columnn in the MS Access database and final query is look like SELECT count(Usercategory) as category_count ,Usercategory FROM tempdata where IssueDate between DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, DATE()) - 0 , 0) and DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, DATE()) + 1, - 1 ) group by category But now i am getting some different error "No value given for one or more required parameters." -- i am not able to figure out any error with this -- can you please advise