# How to select current dates from current month

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-access, c#-2.0

I would like to retrieve the data between 1 -30 of the current month [ i am using MSACCESS Dbase to do so] Below is the query that i am trying  --

```
SELECT count(usercategory) as category_count ,usercategory  FROM user_category 
where IssueDate between DATEADD('m', DATEDIFF('m', 0, DATE()) - 0 , 0) and  DATEADD('m',     DATEDIFF('m', 0, DATE()) + 1, - 1 ) group by usercategory
```

Data that i am holding in my MSACCESS Dbase  -

```
Category1   9/7/2013 12:00:00 AM
Category1   9/8/2013 12:00:00 AM
Category2   10/8/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

so output should have only 2 records 
but my query is giving no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query I think you need.  All the functions it uses are always available in Access SQL regardless of whether the query is run from within an Access session or from without (as in your c# situation).

The db engine will evaluate both those `DateSerial` expressions once, then use their results to filter the result set.  This approach will be especially fast with an index on `IssueDate`.

```sql
SELECT
    Count(usercategory) AS category_count,
    usercategory
FROM user_category 
WHERE
        IssueDate >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)
    AND IssueDate < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) + 1, 0)
GROUP BY usercategory;
```

Here is an Access Immediate window session which explains the logic for those `DateSerial` expressions ...

```vb
? Date()
9/6/2013 
? Year(Date())
 2013 
? Month(Date())
 9 
' get the date for first of this month ...
? DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)
9/1/2013 
' now get the date for the last of this month ...
? DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) + 1, 0)
9/30/2013
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help ...but Now i am getting error "Undefined function  YEAR " :(  i ran the query in VS using Server Explorer --pls advise

Comment: That must be a misleading error message because `Year()` is always available in Access SQL.  Do you have Access available?  If so, try the query there first ... that effort should provide better information about the nature of the problem.

Comment: When i am running the query in VS - i am getting "No value given for one or more required parameters "

Comment: @Dipesh try my edit with `Now` and `BETWEEN`. Also make sure you're using Access Engine e.g. accdb12

Comment: @Dipesh I had a logic error in the original version.  `DateSerial` should use `Date()` instead of `IssueDate` with `Year()` and `Month()`.

Comment: Thanks HansUp - i have changed the query [as you mentioned] but still no records are appearing :(

Comment: Try the query directly in an Access session (instead of from c#) and tell us what happens.