# Nested parentheses in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, parentheses

I've been reworking the parentheses on this query for a bit to no avail.  Can someone point me to the particular spot that is likely causing the error?  Here's the error message:

[image]

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
tExceptionsAll1.ID, 
tExceptionsAll1.CardholderName, 
PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.PERSON_ID, 
tExceptionsAll1.CardType, 
tExceptionsAll1.Duration, 
tExceptionsAll1.ExceptionType, 
tExceptionsAll1.STL AS [Exp STL], 
tExceptionsAll1.CL AS [Exp CL], 
PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card STL], 
PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card CL], 
tExceptionsAll1.TerminationDate, 
tExceptionsAll1.DCMNames, 
tExceptionsAll1.ReminderDate
FROM PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD 
INNER JOIN tExceptionsAll1 ON (PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.CARD_ID = CLNG(tExceptionsAll1.CardID)) 
      AND (CLNG(PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.PERSON_ID) = tExceptionsAll1.CardholderUIN)
WHERE (
  ((tExceptionsAll1.STL)>0) 
  And ((tExceptionsAll1.CL)>0) 
  And ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT)<>tExceptionsAll1.STL) 
  And ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT)<>tExceptionsAll1.CL) 
  And ((tExceptionsAll1.TerminationDate) Is Null)
) 
OR (
  ((tExceptionsAll1.TempSTL)>0) 
  And ((tExceptionsAll1.TempCL)>0) 
  And ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT)<>tExceptionsAll1.TempSTL) 
  And ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT)<>tExceptionsAll1.TempCL) 
  And ((tExceptionsAll1.TerminationDate) Is Null) 
  And ((tExceptionsAll1.ReminderDate) < getdate())
);
```

Comment: Seems fine to me on first read; you have way too many parentheses that are unnecessary, ie. `((tExceptionsAll1.STL)>0)` can just be `tExceptionsAll1.STL)>0`, and you should alias tables in join so it reads easier, ie. `from FROM PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD as X`, then you can just use `X` to refer to that table in your `select` and `where` clauses

Comment: The error message shows a single right parentheses after getDate() but your code has two, is this really the code that generated that error?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: [Access has no `getdate` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18668805/14660).

---

But let's make that query easier to read anyway.

Spacing the query out can make it much easier to follow.

```
SELECT
    tExceptionsAll1.ID,
    tExceptionsAll1.CardholderName,
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.PERSON_ID,
    tExceptionsAll1.CardType, 
    tExceptionsAll1.Duration,
    tExceptionsAll1.ExceptionType,
    tExceptionsAll1.STL AS [Exp STL],
    tExceptionsAll1.CL AS [Exp CL], 
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card STL],
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card CL], 
    tExceptionsAll1.TerminationDate,
    tExceptionsAll1.DCMNames,
    tExceptionsAll1.ReminderDate
FROM PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD
INNER JOIN tExceptionsAll1 
    ON (PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.CARD_ID = CLNG(tExceptionsAll1.CardID)) AND
       (CLNG(PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.PERSON_ID) = tExceptionsAll1.CardholderUIN)
WHERE (
    ((tExceptionsAll1.STL)>0) And
    ((tExceptionsAll1.CL)>0) And
    ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT)<>tExceptionsAll1.STL) And
    ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT)<>tExceptionsAll1.CL) And
    ((tExceptionsAll1.TerminationDate) Is Null)
)
    OR 
(
    ((tExceptionsAll1.TempSTL)>0) And
    ((tExceptionsAll1.TempCL)>0) And
    ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT)<>tExceptionsAll1.TempSTL) And
    ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT)<>tExceptionsAll1.TempCL) And
    ((tExceptionsAll1.TerminationDate) Is Null) And
    ((tExceptionsAll1.ReminderDate) < getdate())
);
```

A good text editor, such as [Atom](https://atom.io) will match parens for you. They all appear to balance fine.

While parens are good to make some precedence issues explicit, like that `or`, too many just gum things up. There's no need to put parens around every comparison. Let's strip some out. Let's also alias the tables to eliminate redundancy.

```
SELECT
    tea1.ID,
    tea1.CardholderName,
    pidc.PERSON_ID,
    tea1.CardType, 
    tea1.Duration,
    tea1.ExceptionType,
    tea1.STL AS [Exp STL],
    tea1.CL AS [Exp CL], 
    pidc.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card STL],
    pidc.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card CL], 
    tea1.TerminationDate,
    tea1.DCMNames,
    tea1.ReminderDate
FROM PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD pidc
INNER JOIN tExceptionsAll1 tea1 
    ON pidc.CARD_ID = CLNG(tea1.CardID) AND
       CLNG(pidc.PERSON_ID) = tea1.CardholderUIN
WHERE (
    tea1.STL > 0 AND
    tea1.CL  > 0 AND
    pidc.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT <> tea1.STL AND
    pidc.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT <> tea1.CL  AND
    tea1.TerminationDate IS NULL
)
    OR 
(
    tea1.TempSTL > 0 AND
    tea1.TempCL  > 0 AND
    pidc.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT <> tea1.TempSTL AND
    pidc.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT <> tea1.TempCL AND
    tea1.TerminationDate IS NULL AND
    tea1.ReminderDate < getdate()
);
```

You can probably come up with better table aliases than I can.

Your error is `Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression`. Now that everything is spaced out, we can see there are just two function calls: `getdate()` and `CLNG()`. [CLNG is an Access fuction](https://ss64.com/access/clng.html) but [`getdate()` is not](https://www.google.com/search?q=getdate&sitesearch=ss64.com%2Faccess%2F)! Instead we should be using [date()](https://ss64.com/access/date.html).

Comment: FYI you started with "Access has no getdate() function" but then kept it in the re-formatted, aliased query

Comment: @user8834780 I don't actually know Access. Once I was done reformatting the query it was obvious there were only two function calls. So I Googled them. :-) Now that the query is well-formatted and the problem is known, fixing it is left as an exercise for somebody who knows Access.

Comment: @user8834780 I've added that as a conclusion. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Thanks for the help- here's an update:  The code provided works (with the 'date()' for 'getdate()' substitution) if I only run one of the WHERE conditions.  The code runs successfully when either condition is used, but when I combine them with the OR I get a 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' error.  I'm not sure how to interpret this. Can someone advise?

Comment: @katie It would be best if you asked a new question about that.